# What is the probability of discrete possible outcomes if we have data?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Lets say I have 4 possible outcomes:

- Click blue button = B
- Click red button = R
- Click green button = G
- Leave without clicking = L

So we assume a theoretical probability of 1/4 for each, meaning equal probability for each.
So:

- B is 25.0%
- R is 25.0%
- G is 25.0%
- L is 25.0%

After 1000 people we get data of what did people choose:

- 750 did B => 75.0%
- 500 did R => 50.0%
- 0   did G => 0%
- 250 did L => 25.0%

According to data, G has 0% probability, but 0% means it's impossible. But we know it's not possible to choose G.

G probability should be less than 25% but bigger then 0%

Is there a way or theories of how to calculate more accurate probability of G?

Comment: emperical research has revealed that the probability connected with G is $0$. So we conclude that **almost surely** (not impossible) it will not happen that the green button will be clicked by an individual. If you want more accurate probability then get the data of e.g. $1000,000$ persons.

Comment: Impossible events certainly have a probability of zero, but there are many events with a probability of zero that are *not* impossible.